# How do I export array to text file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to export the arrays which one containing offsets and one containing timestamps to text file and save them on my PC. I really need all data in these arrays as text file to analyze them for my project.
These are my code about how I add data to array.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _offsets = <Offset>[] ;
  final _timestamp =[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
body: GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (details){
          final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          final localPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
          final timeStamp = DateTime.now();
          //print("localPosition: $localPosition");
          //print("Timestamp: $timeStamp");

          setState(() {
            _offsets.add(localPosition);
            _timestamp.add(timeStamp);
          });
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details){
          setState(() {
            final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            final localPosition = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
            final timeStamp = DateTime.now();
            //print("localPosition: $localPosition");
            //print("Timestamp: $timeStamp");
            _offsets.add(localPosition);
            _timestamp.add(timeStamp);
          });
        },
        onPanEnd: (details){
          setState(()  {
            final timeStamp = DateTime.now();
            _offsets.add(null);
            _timestamp.add(timeStamp);

            
          });
        },
```

and I really don't know what to do next to export the arrays as text file. I've searched but I still don't understand (I quite new to flutter). So, help me please.

Comment: Are you using an emulator? Is this for android or iOS?

Comment: No, I run the program on my phone. It's an android.

Comment: Is knowing how to save the text file *on your PC* part of the question? or is it just writing the arrays to a text file?

Comment: Saving it is also the question. The arrays are the sample result from me drawing lines. I need it as the data to analyze in the calculation part of my project.

Comment: [File read write guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) from  flutter.dev will help in saving file on your device. For directly saving to PC we might need to implement another app which will run on your PC and accept the file/data as a REST call( can be a dart, node.js or any other server app ).